# Loop Iteration wont work as expected

Tags: vba, excel

For some reason its not going to the next cell in the range to check the value.

**Break down of what is meant to happen**

Sub calls Modules1.Getdata

This Checks each row for a notification tag ("True/False"). If true it grabs CompanyNumber calls Module3.Check

Moduel3.Check takes the CompanyNumber checks another sheet/range for Samevalue (Go to next Iteration in Module1.Getdata) Next cell if blank, enter company number etc.

Hope that makes sense.

**Sub**

```
  Sub Workbook_open()

  Call Module1.GetData

  End Sub
```

**Module1.GetData**

```
  Public EmailAddress As String
  Public CompanyNumber As String
  Public Name As String
  Public Comp As String
  Public ID As Integer


  Function GetData()

  Dim LastRow As String
  Dim rng As Range


  Worksheets("DDregister").Activate
  Range("K2").Select


  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

  For Each rng In Range("K2:K" + LastRow)

  If Not rng.Value = vbNullString Then
      Worksheets("DDregister").Activate
      Range("K2").Select

      Select Case rng.Value
        Case 1
            Case Is = "True"
            rng.Select

                Let EmailAddress = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Value
                Let CompanyNumber = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -9).Value
                Let Name = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -8).Value
                Let Comp = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7).Value
                ID = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -10).Value


                Call Module3.Check(EmailAddress, CompanyNumber, Name, Comp)
        Case 2
            Case Is = "False"
     End Select

ElseIf rng.Value = vbNullString Then
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'ThisWorkbook.Close
End If
Next

End Function
```

**Module3.Check**

```
Function Check(EmailAddress As String, CompanyNumber As String, Name As String, Comp As String)

Dim rngCheck As Range
Dim LastRowCheck As String
Dim NewRange As Range

Worksheets("Check").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Select

LastRowCheck = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlDown).Row

For Each rngCheck In Range("B2:B" + LastRowCheck)

   Select Case rngCheck.Value
    Case 1
        Case Is = CompanyNumber
        'Go to next iteration
    Case 2
        Case Is = vbNullString
            ActiveCell.Value = CompanyNumber
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "True"
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = ID
            Call Module2.Email(EmailAddress, CompanyNumber, Name, Comp)

Next

End Function
```

**Module2.Email**

```
Function Email(EmailAddress As String, CompanyNumber As String, Name As String, Comp As String)

Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objMessage.Subject = "Subject " & (Comp)
objMessage.From = "EmailAddress@Address.com"
objMessage.Cc = "EmailAddress@Address.com"
objMessage.To = (EmailAddress)
'MsgBox (EmailAddress)
objMessage.TextBody = "Stuff"

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "x.x.x.x"

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

objMessage.Send

End Function
```

Comment: Are you not getting a type mismatch error on 'For Each rng In Range("K2:K" + LastRow)'  The '+' should be '&'

Comment: Didnt get type mismatch but have changed the + to a & anyway. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: in Module1.GetData remove `Range("K2").Select`

Comment: As a starter, you aren't referencing ranges properly, your code only looks at the activesheet to get the last row. You need to be explicit as VBA will otherwise imply the sheet: `Lastrow = Worksheets("DDregister").Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Your Case Statements seem off to me you are saying if rng.Value = 1 Do nothing if rng.Value = CompanyNumber do nothing if rng.Value = 2 Do nothing if rng.Value = vbNullString do something. Case Is is not assignment it is simply comparing the values of the case and the supplied value. Just because you have indented does not mean anything these re 4 separate Cases and will be evaluated in the same select.

Comment: Thanks Gents, Im a noob so am piecing things together as I go. @Kyle you say im not referencing ranges correctly. could you give me an example how I should be doing this?

Comment: @engineersmnky In the Mod3.Check im trying to go down the rows in column B checking the value gathered in mod1. if the company number equals the company number found (rngCheck.value) in the second sheet to go to next iteration from sheet1. until it cant find the value in sheet2. Then find a blank row and enter the details defined.

Comment: @k3eper I understand what the code is doing but your syntax is wrong. Also some recommendations: Functions return a value since these do not I would make them subs also putting them in the same Module would make more sense and make them easier to call.

Comment: I have done ;) - have a look at the cod e in the original comment

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "True" And "False" Are actually strings and not the boolean values I think GetData should look more like the following:

```
Sub GetData()
    Dim LastRow As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim EmailAddress As String
    Dim CompanyNumber As String
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Comp As String
    Dim ID As Integer

    Worksheets("DDregister").Activate
    Range("K2").Select


    Lastrow = Worksheets("DDregister").Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each rng In Range("K2:K" & LastRow)
      Select Case rng.value
          Case "True"
              EmailAddress = Worksheets("DDregister").Cells(rng.Row,"F").Value
              CompanyNumber = Worksheets("DDregister").Cells(rng.Row,"B").Value
              Name = Worksheets("DDregister").Cells(rng.Row,"C").Value
              Comp = Worksheets("DDregister").Cells(rng.Row,"D").Value
              ID = Worksheets("DDregister").Cells(rng.Row,"A").Value
              Call Module3.Check(EmailAddress, CompanyNumber, Name, Comp)
          Case "False"
          Case vbNullString
              ThisWorkbook.Save
              Application.DisplayAlerts = True
              'ThisWorkbook.Close
     End Select
   Next rng
End Sub
```

Also this is a sub because it does not return anything and why have you put all of these routines in different modules? Since you are passing the values there is no reason to make them global by listing them outside the sub

P.S. I did not fix your other SELECT CASE Statement but it has similar issues. SELECT CASE syntax the way you are using it is as follows

```
 SELECT CASE [expression]
      CASE [condition]
      CASE [condition]
      CASE ELSE
 END SELECT
```

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky Ive changed to the sub rather than Function and ive moved to an IF else statement in mod 3. Any idea why its not cycling through the range in this module?

Comment: did you change your reference to `LastRowCheck` the way @Kyle suggested you do in the GetData? because right now you are using xlDown which is incorrect. unless there are no blanks at all in this column

Comment: Yes its now xlUp as suggested

Comment: The module 3 code changes the sheet and since the ranges are not properly referenced, the code is running on the wrong sheet

Comment: @Kyle Mod 3 is meant to be on a different sheet

Comment: Im trying to get the loop in Mod3 to check through column B, if it finds a exact match to skip to next iteration in mod1 loop. If it cant find an exact match to go to next blank line and add values to that row. then next iteration in mod1 loop

Comment: im trying to create a type of register. and entries need to be updated every 6 months, so looking for a way to automate the checking if they have been renewed or up for renewal. if up for renewal send an email and make a note that its been emailed (second sheet).

Answer (score 0):

How far is this from what you need? It all goes into a single standard module and is a complete replacement for you code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum DataRef
    ID = 1
    CompanyNumber = 2
    Name = 3
    Comp = 4
    Email = 6
End Enum


Sub test()

Dim vData, vSubData
Dim lngRow As Long

With Worksheets("DDregister")
    vData = .Range("A2:K" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row)
End With

If Len(vData(1, 11)) > 0 Then
    For lngRow = LBound(vData) To UBound(vData)
        If vData(lngRow, 11) = "True" Then
            With Worksheets("Check").Columns(2)
                If .Find(vData(lngRow, DataRef.CompanyNumber), , xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                    vSubData = Array(vData(lngRow, DataRef.ID), vData(lngRow, DataRef.CompanyNumber), "True")
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1).Resize(, 3).Value = vSubData
                    SendEmail vData(lngRow, DataRef.Email), vData(lngRow, DataRef.Comp)
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next lngRow
Else
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End If



End Sub

Sub SendEmail(ByVal EmailAddress As String, ByVal Comp As String)

    Dim objMessage As Object

    Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    With objMessage
        .Subject = "Subject " & Comp
        .From = "EmailAddress@Address.com"
        .Cc = "EmailAddress@Address.com"
        .To = EmailAddress
        .TextBody = "Stuff"

        .Configuration.Fields.Item _
            ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

        .Configuration.Fields.Item _
            ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "x.x.x.x"

        .Configuration.Fields.Item _
            ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25

        .Configuration.Fields.Update
        .Send
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out a way to do it myself, I would really appreciate some feedback, as you might have guessed im new to coding lol

```
  Sub GetData()
Dim LastRow As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim EmailAddress As String
Dim CompanyNumber As String
Dim Name As String
Dim Comp As String
Dim ID As Integer
Dim rngCheck As Range
Dim LastRowCheck As String
Dim TodayDate As Date




TodayDate = Date
Worksheets("DDregister").Activate
Range("K2").Select


LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

For Each rng In Range("K2:K" + LastRow)
    Worksheets("DDregister").Activate
  Select Case rng.Value
      Case "True"

            rng.Select
            EmailAddress = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Value
            CompanyNumber = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -9).Value
            Name = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -8).Value
            Comp = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7).Value
            ID = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -10).Value

            Worksheets("Check").Activate
            Range("B2").Select

            LastRowCheck = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

            For Each rngCheck In Range("B2:B" & LastRowCheck)
                Select Case True

                Case ActiveCell.Value = CompanyNumber
                    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                    Exit For

               End Select

                If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
                    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                    ActiveCell.Select
                End If

                If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
                    ActiveCell.Value = CompanyNumber
                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "True"
                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = ID
                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = TodayDate
                    Call Email(EmailAddress, CompanyNumber, Name, Comp)

                 End If
            Next rngCheck

      Case "False"
      Case vbNullString
            Call Module2.MsgPopup

            'CloseBookMsgBox = MsgBox("Do you want to Close the WorkBook", vbYesNo, "WhatsThis")
            '
            If Module2.MsgPopup = vbYes Then
                ThisWorkbook.Save
                ThisWorkbook.Close
            '
            ElseIf Module2.MsgPopup = vbNo Then
                Cancel = "True"
                MsgBox "Please make sure you save changes manually and close the work book!"
            End If

            If Cancel = "True" Then Exit Sub



 End Select
 Next rng
 End Sub

 Sub Email(EmailAddress As String, CompanyNumber As String, Name As String, Comp As String)

 Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
 objMessage.Subject = "stuff" & (Comp)
 objMessage.From = "emailaddress"
 objMessage.Cc = "emailaddress"
 objMessage.to = EmailAddress

 objMessage.TextBody = "stuff"

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "x.x.x.x"

    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

objMessage.Send

End Sub
```

As i will be runing a Scheduled task to execute this on open, I need to add a delayed msgbox as we will need to manual alter the document as well. so if the timeout period is reached i need to default to "no". Im attempting this in the below function (itsnt working atm)

```
 Set objWshell = CreateObject(“WScript.Shell”)
```

**Any help on this part would be great, currently telling me that "Object Required** on this line ^. Even tho it is "set"

```
Public Function MsgPopup(Optional Prompt As String, Optional Buttons As VbMsgBoxStyle = vbOKOnly, Optional Title As String, Optional SecondsToWait As Long = 0) As VbMsgBoxResult

Dim objWshell As Object

Set objWshell = CreateObject(“WScript.Shell”)

MsgPopup = objWshell.Popup(Prompt, 20, "Do you want to Close the WorkBook", vbYesNo)

Set objWshell = Nothing

End Function
```